# Blendered Rendered my (.mov) Animation BUT didn't save it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

So I waited three days for this animation to be done rendering. Checked last night before going to bed and saw it would be done by the time I woke up today, yay! Woke up, and I can't find the saved .mov file anywhere. I thought maybe it overwrote the first file I made, which was rendered with very few samples (25) and at 50% resolution, but when I open this one lonely files it is DEFINETLY the old sample file it says the dimensions of the file are 960 x 540 (which would be 50% of the resolution of the new rendered animation right?) and it says it was made on the 3rd, which today is not.

However despite this, the blender window has switched over to the Render Result view as it's supposed to when it's done rendering and it also allows me to play back my lovely new animation if I go to "Render" at the top of the window and select "Play Rendered Animation".

So if I can play the new rendered animation... and the rendering is complete (I didn't get a photo cause I didn't know this was going to happen but the little "Completed" text had showed up at the top fo the "Render Result" window) then WHERE IS IT?

I needed this thing done by midnight tonight, I even calculated how long it would take to render based on minutes per frame to make SURE it would be done in time... I'm hoping this is just some weird little newbie thing I just missed and is super obvious to all of you kind people and has a easy fix without me having to re-render the whole thing...

- Can I just re-save the rendered animation without re-rendering?
- Is it actually that file shown in the Finder window?

Anyways here is the screengrab so you can see what's up. (The Finder window i've got on the left side of the image shows the original, low resolution animation I test rendered. You can see the dimensions don't match up to what they should be if Blender had indeed simply overwritten this file with my new 100% resolution render...)

[image]

Comment: The location where the file is rendered is determined in the output section of the properties window. As a piece of advice: **Never ever render directly into a video format**. Render as an image sequence first and encode to video later. If you render for 3 days and have any kind of issue you loose all of your work. If you render as images first, you get to keep all of the rendered frames...

Comment: I've checked the folder i've selected in my output and the file I've got displayed on the left is the only file in there that is a .mov
So is there a chance something went wrong then and instead of getting a corrupted file so I atleast knew what happened is just didn't save anything?

The problem is I have audio synced in Blender to this thing so I was hoping to be able to export it with the audio? Which I couldn't achieve with stills... Thanks for the tip though, sad it doesn't help right now haha :'(

Comment: I don't know what it does on Mac, but on Windows 'play rendered animation' opens a new window in which it plays the animation, with the complete path of the file as the title of this window.